# Creating table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to create a table with javascript. I have the below code -

```
function resultCreate(){
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width = '500px';
    tbl.style.marginTop = '30px';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        tr.style.border = '1px sold black';
        for(var j=0;j<6;j++){
            if(i === 0 && (j === 3 || j === 4 || j === 5)){
                break;
            }

            else if(i === 1 && (j === 0 || j === 1)){
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.style.border = '1px sold black';
            }

            else{
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello'));
                td.style.border = '1px sold black';
                if(i === 0 && j === 2){ 
                    td.setAttribute('colSpan', '4');
                }
                if(i === 2 && j === 0){
                    td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '4');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}

resultCreate();
```

This creates the following table - 
[image]

I don't want the last column.
I tried using the same logic as my colSpan, by adding

```
else if((i == 3 && j == 0) || (i == 4 && j == 0) || (i == 5 && j == 0)){
                break;
}
```

But it deletes the entire 3rd,4th and 5th rows except the first column.

[image: Like this]

The entire code looks like this -

```
function resultCreate(){
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width = '500px';
    tbl.style.marginTop = '30px';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        tr.style.border = '1px sold black';
        for(var j=0;j<6;j++){
            if(i === 0 && (j === 3)){
                break;
            }
            else if((i == 3 && j == 0) || (i == 4 && j == 0) || (i == 5 && j == 0)){
                break;
            }
            else if(i === 1 && (j === 0 || j === 1)){
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.style.border = '1px sold black';
            }

            else{
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello'));
                td.style.border = '1px sold black';
                if(i === 0 && j === 2){ 
                    td.setAttribute('colSpan', '4');
                }
                if(i === 2 && j === 0){
                    td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '4');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}

resultCreate();
```

Can anybody help me out please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and use the code snippet to make a fully reproductible problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  function resultCreate(){
        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        tbl.style.width = '500px';
        tbl.style.marginTop = '30px';
        tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
        for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
            var tr = tbl.insertRow();
            tr.style.border = '1px sold black';
            for(var j=0;j<6;j++){
                if(i === 0 && (j === 3 || j === 4 || j === 5)){
                    break;
                }
                else if( i > 2 && j === 5){
                    break;
                }
                else if(i === 1 && (j === 0 || j === 1)){
                    var td = tr.insertCell();
                    td.style.border = '1px sold black';
                }

                else{
                    var td = tr.insertCell();
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hello'));
                    td.style.border = '1px sold black';
                    if(i === 0 && j === 2){ 
                        td.setAttribute('colSpan', '4');
                    }
                    if(i === 2 && j === 0){
                        td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '4');
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        body.appendChild(tbl);
    }

    resultCreate();
```

Comment: you could also change  (j === 3 || j === 4 || j === 5) to (j >2)

Comment: Thanks a ton. If it's not a problem,could you tell me where was I going wrong in my code?

Comment: "Try this" is rarely helpful to anyone other than the OP. Please describe what you changed and why.

Comment: the logic of the first if not to add any element when j  > 2 since the third element is bigger .. With the same logic I added the if else so as not to add any element for the 4th row and below since the first position is occupied by the "bigger" first element of the 3rd row

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below, "i==2, j==0" with colspan=4 takes up space, so "i==3->5, j==0" pushes into the second column, therefore resulting in an extra column at the end.

```js
function resultCreate(){
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width = '500px';
    tbl.style.marginTop = '30px';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        tr.style.border = '1px solid blue';
        for(var j=0;j<6;j++){
            if(i === 0 && (j === 3 || j === 4 || j === 5)){
                break;
            }
            else if(i === 1 && (j === 0 || j === 1)){
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.style.border = '1px solid green';
            }

            else{
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('i='+i+' j='+j));
                td.style.border = '1px solid yellow';
                if(i === 0 && j === 2){ 
                    td.setAttribute('colSpan', '4');
                }
                if(i === 2 && j === 0){
                    td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '4');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}

resultCreate();
```

The solution below is accurate to what your intention was, by ignoring i==3->5 and j==0.
But any solution that ignores one set of columns of i=3->5 (i>2) will work.

```js
function resultCreate(){
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width = '500px';
    tbl.style.marginTop = '30px';
    tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        tr.style.border = '1px solid blue';
        for(var j=0;j<6;j++){
            if(i >=3 && j === 0 ) continue; 
            if(i === 0 && (j === 3 || j === 4 || j === 5)){
                break;
            }
            else if(i === 1 && (j === 0 || j === 1)){
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.style.border = '1px solid green';
            }

            else{
                var td = tr.insertCell();
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i+' '+j));
                td.style.border = '1px solid yellow';
                if(i === 0 && j === 2){ 
                    td.setAttribute('colSpan', '4');
                }
                if(i === 2 && j === 0){
                    td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '4');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}

resultCreate();
```

Also you spelled solid wrong, so the cell borders don't actually show up.